# unity3d 2017.3 can't build any project error

Tags: unity-game-engine

Errors:

```
- ArgumentException: The Assembly UnityEngine is referenced by UnityEngine.UI ('D:/Program Files/Unity2018/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/GUISystem/Standalone/UnityEngine.UI.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 cache, BuildTarget target) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:156)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[] paths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, BuildTarget target) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:196)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

- Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

- UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0020e] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:181 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00065] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:88 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

I have no script errors, after updating to unity3d 2017.3 (was 2017.2 before) I can't even build an empty new project.

Comment: try deleting the `index-local.xml` file usually found at `C:\ProgramData\Unity\index-local.xml` while Unity is closed. Reopen the project, and try to build again.

Comment: Thx u so mush man, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is simply an [answer from the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223692/unity3d-2017-3-cant-build-any-project-error/51922697#comment83428951_48223692) given by hammus which seems to work (so that others can find the solution as fast as possible):

> Try deleting the index-local.xml file usually found at
>   `C:\ProgramData\Unity\index-local.xml` while Unity is closed. Reopen
>   the project and try to build again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with removing open gles3 support in other settings (graffics api). maybe you can  solve with this

Comment: could you elaborate your point by posting some code / action flow?